# Issues understanding Rudin's proof of convergence of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, there is a proof concerning the convergence of a sequence. Here's the theorem:

[image: 1]

And then the proof goes like this:

[image]

I have difficulties uderstanding how $|\alpha _{j,n}-\alpha_{j}|< \frac{\varepsilon }{\sqrt{k}}$ implies  $|\mathbf{x}_{n}-\mathbf{x}| = \Bigl\{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}|\alpha _{j,n}-\alpha _{j}|^{2}\Bigr\}^{1/2}$

Comment: The equality $|\mathbf{x}_{n}-\mathbf{x}| = \left\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}|\alpha _{j,n}-\alpha _{j}|^{2}\right\}^{1/2}$ is by definition of $|\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality
$$
|\mathbf{x}_{n}-\mathbf{x}| = 
\biggl\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}|\alpha _{j,n}-\alpha _{j}|^{2}\biggr\}^{1/2}
$$
is simply the definition of the left-hand side.

Since each summand in the right-hand side is less than $\varepsilon^2/k$, the sum is less than $k\frac{\varepsilon^2}{k}=\varepsilon^2$ and, taking the square root you finish.